# django-allauth configuration for multilangiage website

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth 0.17.0 with Django 1.5.6 and I have a question for multilanguage setup. I will use only two languages, english and chinese. Did someone use it for that kind of setup? What is the best and fastest solution to do that?

I was planning to use something like this in urls:
(r'^(?P\w{2})/accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

so I can grab "activeLanguage" and prepare templates for each language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need custom setup to make it work with django allauth.

In a project of mine, I have in my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('allauth.urls')),
)
```

It works as expected (e.g. you can access login at `/en/login`).

If you want to translate the templates, you should probably not prepare a template for each language.

Instead, you can override the provided allauth templates. For the login template, just create a `templates/account/login.html` file in any of your project app. 
Then you can write your template using [django's translation mechanisms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code).